# Does Adding Calculations in Constraints Reduce System Performance?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner and just started out learning swift and have a question in layout constraints.

If I were to type out a constraint for an imageView in a Table View Cell like so:

```
            func setConstraints(){
//Method 1            
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                clientPhoto.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.leftAnchor,constant: 12),
                clientPhoto.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor,constant: 2),
                clientPhoto.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
                clientPhoto.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 23)
                ])

    //OR
//Method 2  
     NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                clientPhoto.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.leftAnchor,constant: 12),
                clientPhoto.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: baseView.topAnchor,constant: 2),
                clientPhoto.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIscreen.main.bounds.width/2),
                clientPhoto.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/4)
                ])
            }
        }
```

Of the methods 1 & 2 written above, which is faster in execution and by how much? I've been told that having calculations in the constraints slows down the performance of the system.

If the way of constants with numbers is better, how do I account for the changes in screen width and height when trying to display the UI with same ratio in different devices(iPhone SE - XS Max)?

Comment: In theory, method 1 will be slightly faster, because you use a constant. But because this is only a single division, you won't notice any difference, I am sure that you can't even measure the difference because it is so small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "No, there will be no significant difference between this two ways".

And here's why: you actually calculate the values once and set the values. No more caluclations needed. It's very very fast.

I'm not sure what've you heard about the layout peformance, but the constraints in a nutshell is a complex system of equations, so every time system needs layout any of subview – it recalculates all the equatations. And this is what takes significant time to do – to solve all the equatations. So you ease the system work if you set a simple constraints with a constants (like you do in your question).
"A constraint with a calculation" you've heard about is probably a constraints with equatation like "the width BINDED to the half of height of another view".

Comment: Then how do i account for the different screen sizes of iPhones if constants make it easier for the system to process? Wouldn't there be an offset if I designed a UI for a 5S and then try to view it in an 8 plus or vice versa?

Comment: 1. You're free to use "dynamic" constraints. There is no such rule as "don't use the complex constraint or your app will hangs". It is just better to not overuse it. Simple constrains bound to screen size is still works very fast, until you add many more complex constrains.
2. Profiling is your friend. Measure the time system spent on relayout and fps value to understand, where you can optimize your constraints if it needs optimization at all.
3. So, don't overcomplicate this at the moment. Just use the constraints until you find that they really hurt your app :)